# Hive CLI '-e' & '-f' options not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using Horton-works Hadoop solution and I'm unable to execute hive command line interface commands.

1. Using -e option, with command as follows

   ```
   C:\somepath\hive-0.11\bin>hive -e 'select * from sampletable'
   ```

   Here, I get the error

   > 'ParseException', cannot recognize input near '', '' in select clause.
2. Using -f option, with commands as follows

   ```
   C:\somepath\hive-0.11\bin>hive -f /user/myusername/sample.sql
   ```

   Here I get the error

   > unable to read the file at specified location.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what is going on in case `1)`. Maybe the windows shell expands things in a weird way? Try `hive -e "select * from sampletable"`

With your second one, I'm guessing you are passing in a hdfs path for some reason. This is most certainly not what you want, as it is looking for a file in your local file system. Where is it locally?:

```
hive -f C:\path\to\sample.sql
```